# Why is axios not using the settings in nuxt.config.js?

Tags: axios, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

The axios settings for baseURL and browserBaseURL in nuxt.config.js are not being used by axios and the requests are going to localhost instead.

Here's an extract of nuxt.config.js:

```
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://192.168.8.137:8081',
    browserBaseURL: 'http://192.168.8.137:8081'
  },
```

And here's the code in the vue file:

```
<template>
  <v-treeview
    v-model="tree"
    :open="open"
    :items="items"
    activatable
    item-key="id"
    :load-children="listDir"
    :active.sync="active"
    return-object
  >
 ....
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
      ....
      methods: {
        async listDir(item) {
          // let url = 'http://192.168.8.137:8081/filemanager/ls'  // Works fine if hardcoded here
          let url = '/filemanager/ls'
          await axios.get(url)
            .then(....
```

I think the problem is that I'm using axios.get(url) and not $this.axios.get(url), however my method is being called from a vuetify treeview component and $this is not available.

How do I get hold of $this.axios?

The code works fine if I hardcode the URL into the axios call.

Comment: in Nuxt.js you can use `fetch` and everything will work since fetch is polyfilled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

you are importing "clean" axios module.
You need to use axios instance created by nuxt itself.

In component (or in Vue actions) use just (without importing axios)

```
this.$axios.get(...)
```

or (convenient $get method returns response data instead response object)

```
this.$axios.$get(...)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I managed to fix it by using this.$nuxt.$axios, but your answer of this.$axios is better.